# How is my GAE app able to run without app.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, app.yaml

Although I started development for Google App Engine using Endpoints a while ago, I hadn't noticed this - Google's ref. page for Project structure says this:

> Your development file hierarchy should look like this:
>
> ```
> MyDir/
>   [pom.xml]
>   [build.gradle]
>   [index.yaml]
>   [cron.yaml]
>   [dispatch.yaml]
>   src/main/
>     appengine/
>       app.yaml
>     docker/
>       [Dockerfile]
>     java/
>       com.example.mycode/
>         MyCode.java
>     webapp/
>       [index.html]
>       [jsp.jsp]
>       WEB-INF/
>         [web.xml]
> ```
>
> You'll need to define an **app.yaml** file that looks like this:
>   ...

Note that the app.yaml is deemed compulsory as per the docs. In my case, I spawned a backend module(through the Wizard) in Android Studio that builds on Gradle. I have been able to build and deploy this module on GAE successfully but now I needed to switch from automatic scaling to basic/manual scaling, I found this to be done through app.yaml file.

Here is the thing: I *don't* have an app.yaml in place and it works fine. Where is then the config info. that GAE requires to deploy the App.

Specifically,

- app.yaml specifies the environment - Java. But, I found the java plugin in build.gradle for that. Aren't 2 config places for the same thing confusing?
- Is it possible to ditch app.yaml entirely for equivalent config. in build.gradle?
- Why is Google claiming app.yaml to be compulsory when I am able to do without it?

Comment: The Java runtime is special and is known to have XML config instead of YAML.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi : Where can I change the scaling config. for the App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App Engine Java runtime uses its own configuration schema in XML, while others are YAML.

To set the scaling elements, follow the official [reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements).